# Post web method not firing + asp.net core webapi

Tags: asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I am implementing CRUD operations using EF7 and storedprocudures in asp.net core web api project. I have finished implementing the get methods and left with  the insert method. I am using Postman to test the web methods. I have written the implementation for Create but unable the post the information via postman isn't hitting the Create web method in the controller. Could somebody let me know what the problem could be. The route of the get and post is the same except the method signature is different.

**Controller**

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMoviesRepository _moviesRepository;

    public MoviesController(IMoviesRepository moviesRepository)
    {
        _moviesRepository = moviesRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Movies")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetMovies()
    {
        var movies = await _moviesRepository.GetMovies();
        var results = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MoviesDto>>(movies);
        return Ok(results);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Movies/{ID}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetMovie(int ID)
    {
        var movie = await _moviesRepository.GetMovie(ID);
        var results = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MoviesDto>>(movie);
        return Ok(results);

    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("api/Movies")]
    public IActionResult CreateMovie([FromBody] MoviesDto movies)
    {

        if (movies == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        // Check if movie exists
        var movie =  _moviesRepository.GetMovie(movies.MovieId);
        if (movie == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var results = Mapper.Map<Movies>(movies);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             _moviesRepository.AddMovie(results);
        }

        return Ok(results);

    }
}
```

**Postman**
[image]

Comment: It looks like you forgot to add antiforgery cookie to request. Or it's deserialization error. Or something else. You could debug your program and check its log to collect more info. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed. I had to remove the anti-forgery token